# Which web.xml to use?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, web, web.xml

Which `web.xml` should I use? `web.xml` in the project folder or `web.xml` in `servers` folder?

[image: pic]

Which should I use?

Can I use both?

Comment: This has already been explained - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937226/

Comment: use the WEB-INF -> web.xml file.