# How to set Content-Type for auto-delivered file in GlassFish?

Tags: servlets, glassfish, mime-types

When deploying a .war file to a GlassFish Server (4.1 currently), the GF server automatically delivers files from the `WEB-INF/` folder. (Unless I override their addresses by specifying a Servlet, that is.)

Actually when deploying the .war file to the GF server, it extracts those files under `WEB-INF/` to `{gf-home}/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/{app-name}`.
Then it delivers them when accessing `http://{hostname}:8080/{app-name}/{path}`.

Now when accessing .json files, the server does NOT send the HTTP `Content-Type: application/json` header. 
This results in the page not loading properly, FireFox console showing me a `XML Parsing Error: not well-formed` exception, even though the file contents are exactly the same.
So my guess is that it's the missing Content-Type tag.

**How can I change this mime-mapping for the app/project itself?**

From the pages I have seen so far, it is possible to redefine this behaviour in the `{gf-home}/glassfish/domains/domain1/default-web.xml` file, defining the `mime-mapping`. But presuming I cannot access that file, only upload .war files. *Is there any solution?* Is it possible to pack a `default-web.xml` somewhere into the .war file?

The other solution I can think of at the moment is to override the specific .json files' addresses with a servlet and adding the `Content-Type` header in Java. But I'm not sure if there is a foolproof way of accessing and reading the .json files at runtime, but without moving them anywhere in the Java source code, but leaving them in the WEB-INF/ folder? *Any suggestions?*

Comment: It's a bit vague why you explicitly wanted to edit GlassFish's `default-web.xml` instead of webapp's own `web.xml`. Can't you even edit the webapp's `web.xml` in first place or was you just not aware that it should be done over there?

Comment: No, I was not aware I could just edit web.xml... Didnt have that file around, and was pretty confused with all the xyz-xmls flying around. So I just redefine some mime-mappings in META-INF/web.xml, and that's it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *How can I change this mime-mapping for the app/project itself?*

By declaring the `<mime-mapping>` entries in webapp's own `/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

Since Servlet version 3.0, the `web.xml` file became optional. That'll perhaps explain why you could find no one. You can just supply your own in the webapp. GlassFish 4.1 is a Servlet 3.1 capable container, so the below Servlet 3.1 compatible `web.xml` should get you started:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <!-- Config here. -->
</web-app>
```

In your specific case, you'll need the below mime mapping in there:

```xml
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>json</extension>
        <mime-type>application/json</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
```

#### See also:

- [What is conf/web.xml used for in Tomcat as oppsed to the one in WEB-INF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937226/what-is-conf-web-xml-used-for-in-tomcat-as-oppsed-to-the-one-in-web-inf/)
- [How to set the content type on the servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216190/how-to-set-the-content-type-on-the-servlet/)
- [How to find servlet API version for glassfish server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777179/how-to-find-servlet-api-version-for-glassfish-server)
- [Servlet 3.1 specification (PDF) chapter 10.13](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-3.1/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf)